# Custom error message on invalid input

Tags: solidity, remix, custom-errors

I have a function that requires two inputs: string and array of uint256. Here is the general structure of the function (only showing relevant part of the contract):

```
function test(string memory _a, uint256[] memory _b) public {
        ...
    }
```

In testing with Remix, output is as expected. Example: I can pass XYZ,[1,2,3] and it does what I want. If I pass XYZ,1, then I get an error as expected:

```
Error encoding arguments: Error: expected array value (argument=null, value="5", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.5.0)
```

Is it possible to customize this error message even further for the ignorant user? For example, what if I wanted to tell the user: ***"Ensure you enclose the array in brackets."***

I've looked at *revert* and *require*, but haven't found examples that check the input type and throw a custom error; I don't need to check the value, only the type.

Comment: I think these errors are inbuilt and are returned from the EVM. I think these errors can be handled only from the front end, not from the contract.

Comment: @shubhamskatel That error message is from Remix, before executing the transaction (the transaction is never executed).